# How to map a SQL profiler captured 'exec sp_executesql' to stored procedure name in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-profiler, sp-executesql

I have a huge SQL server database. I want to re-write an application. For that I want to reuse the database which has many tables, views and stored procedure. I am using SQL Profiler tool to map the application functionality to database. In Profiler, I am capturing

```
SP:Starting 
SP:Completed 
SP:StmtStarting 
RPC:Completed
SQL:BatchCompleted 
SQL:BatchStarting
```

In my Profiler trace I have captured an `RPC:Completed` event class and the textdata contains

> exec sp_executesql N'Select Some query' @var=N'value'".

What is `sp_executesql` and how can I know the exact name of the stored procedure called?

Comment: *"What is sp_executesql"*: [sp_executesql](https://www.google.com/search?q=sp_executesql). *"how can I know the exact name of the stored procedure called"* In your example it wasn't an SP, it was a `SELECT` statement: `N'Select Some query`

Comment: `RPC:Completed` fires not only for stored procedures but for any query parameterized by the client. Note that the `exec sp_executesql` is synthesized by the profiler: the client need not actually call `sp_executesql` explicitly for this to appear, it rewrites the RPC call to a form you could execute in your query window. Note also that there's a difference between the client issuing a (parameterized) `EXEC procname` query, and the client directly calling the stored procedure with parameters (the former will show `sp_executesql`, the latter will not).

Comment: @Larnu, So if it wasn't a SELECT statement then SP name would have come?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, So the clients' parameterized query will not be stored in the database, It is only in their Application code?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, _Also that there's a difference between the client issuing a (parameterized) EXEC procname query, and the client directly calling the stored procedure with parameters (the former will show sp_executesql, the latter will not)._ How will I capture the latter SP

Comment: Yes, query texts are only in the application's code. And you capture the SP with `RPC:Completed`, but the client may never issue a sproc call (`CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`, or whatever the moral equivalent on their end is). Try filtering out `sp_executesql` for the object name to see if any direct calls are made.

Answer (score 2):

In your trace you need to add additional column `ObjectName` which show exact sproc name when you click on `RPC:Completed` event. `ObjectName` can be seen when you check `'Show all columns'`

[image]

Comment: Object name is selected, and it shows 'exec sp_executesql'

Comment: Can you share screen shot of same?